# how to give unique id to buttons generated dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<table border="0" class="tableDemo bordered">
    <tr class="ajaxTitle">
        <th width="2%">Sr</th>
        <th >SM</th>
        <th >Campaign</th>
        <th >Day1</th>
        <th >Day2</th>
        <th >Day3</th>
        <th >Day4</th>
        <th >Day5</th>
        <th>Day6</th>
        <th >Day7</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(count($records)){
     $i = 1;    
     foreach($records as $key=>$eachRecord){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo$eachRecord['id']; ?>">
        <td><?php $i++; ?></td>
        <td class="sm"><?php echo $eachRecord['sm'];?></td>
        <td class="campaign"><?php echo $eachRecord['campaign'];?></td>
        <td class="day1"><?php echo $eachRecord['day1'];?>         
        <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button></td>

        <td class="day2"><?php echo $eachRecord['day2'];?>        
         <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button></td>

        <td class="day3"><?php echo $eachRecord['day3'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day4"><?php echo $eachRecord['day4'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button></td>

        <td class="day5"><?php echo $eachRecord['day5'];?>       
         <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day6"><?php echo $eachRecord['day6'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day7"><?php echo $eachRecord['day7'];?>       
         <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button> </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $eachRecord['id'];?>" class="ajaxEdit"><img src="" class="eimage"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $eachRecord['id'];?>" class="ajaxDelete"><img src="" class="dimage"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

This is my table format. I have used ajax and jquery mechanism to dynamically generate new rows where same buttons will be cloned. I want to generate a unique id to each button that is generated. Can anyone please  help me on this task?

Comment: @Jdpatel dude.. Unique ID's means it's NOT the same.... So his question is legit..

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()" id="<?php echi 'id_'.$key ?>">view</button></td>

Comment: Thanks dude..let me make my question clear...as you can see i have 7 columns in each column a button together with textbox..i can give id to first 7 buttons using id property..but when new row is generated dynamically the new 7 buttons will be copy of same first 7 buttons right...i want to generate unique id's to those buttons as well...thank you..@Dennis,@jd patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of variable `i` to generate button ids. Put some string for button id and append variable `i` as shown below

```
<button onclick="myFunction()" id="firstBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button></td>
```

So whole table look like

```
<table border="0" class="tableDemo bordered">
    <tr class="ajaxTitle">
        <th width="2%">Sr</th>
        <th >SM</th>
        <th >Campaign</th>
        <th >Day1</th>
        <th >Day2</th>
        <th >Day3</th>
        <th >Day4</th>
        <th >Day5</th>
        <th>Day6</th>
        <th >Day7</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    if(count($records)){
     $i = 1;    
     foreach($records as $key=>$eachRecord){
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php echo$eachRecord['id']; ?>">
        <td><?php $i++; ?></td>
        <td class="sm"><?php echo $eachRecord['sm'];?></td>
        <td class="campaign"><?php echo $eachRecord['campaign'];?></td>
        <td class="day1"><?php echo $eachRecord['day1'];?>         
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="firstBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button></td>

        <td class="day2"><?php echo $eachRecord['day2'];?>        
         <button onclick="myFunction()" id="secondBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button></td>

        <td class="day3"><?php echo $eachRecord['day3'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="thirdBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day4"><?php echo $eachRecord['day4'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="forthBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button></td>

        <td class="day5"><?php echo $eachRecord['day5'];?>       
         <button onclick="myFunction()" id="fiftBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day6"><?php echo $eachRecord['day6'];?>        
        <button onclick="myFunction()" id="sixthBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button> </td>

        <td class="day7"><?php echo $eachRecord['day7'];?>       
         <button onclick="myFunction()" id="seventhBtn<?php $i; ?>">view</button> </td>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $eachRecord['id'];?>" class="ajaxEdit"><img src="" class="eimage"></a>
            <a href="javascript:;" id="<?php echo $eachRecord['id'];?>" class="ajaxDelete"><img src="" class="dimage"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php }
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you..@Bhushan Kawadkar for the answer...But i want unique or incremental id to be generated to dynamically generated buttons..

Comment: This will generate unique and incremental id as you are doing `$i++` in first `td`, so you will get ids like firstBtn1, firstBtn2, firstBtn3....

Comment: the code I provided will create id for buttons only and not the row

Comment: Could you please help me how to store these id in mysql database on button click..